# Invisible menu Item

Tags: mobile, menu, invisible

On the page [http://www.voorlopig.eu/particulieren](http://www.voorlopig.eu/particulieren/) I have a mobile menu (max-width: 768px). For some reason, the parent menu items - who should be next to the + when you open the menu - are invisible. They are there in the code, but I cannot see them.

Tried everything, but no luck...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Stefaan

Comment: Are you using de default wordpress loop to display the menu items?

Comment: Hi thommylue, thanks for your feedback! How do I check that?

Comment: Hi Stefaan! Oh, I thought you're making your own theme. Is the mobile menu a plug-in?

Comment: No, I based it on this tutorial: http://ozzyrodriguez.com/tutorials/genesis/genesis-responsive-menu-2-0/

Comment: It seems like this plug-in adds some html tags to the menu, which are styled by some CSS from your custom menu. But if i inspect the mobile menu I see that there's no text between the button tags: <button class="sub-menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>

Comment: That's correct. But if you inspect the mobile menu, you'll see there is a <a>  link with a <span> inside just before. That's where the text is.

Comment: I don't understand how this should work, or how you could acces te page "Opleiding&Boeken" if the toggle button is full width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it a little bit out, but I have to work by myself now.
I added

```
.sub-menu-toggle {
width: 40px;
}
```

Now the titles are visible and you can click on them as a hyperlink. The buttons to expand the submenus are still clickable and working.